# IBM Tivoli Analytics on Bluemix

Tags: external, analytics, ibm-cloud, tivoli

I was wondering if you can somehow connect your Tivoli Analytic tools on an external machine to the Bluemix Platform?

Comment: Do you mean you want feed performance metrics and logs etc. from Bluemix applications to your Tivoli Analytics tools? Where is your Tivoli tools running? Behind your enterprise firewall?

Comment: Can you explain more what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your exact requirement but Bluemix provides option to integrate with any on-premise system like database , web services. Similarly I guess you can try connecting Tivoli tool. Try this url and also pls. provide more details on your usecase scenario.
.
. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/cloud_to_on_premise_web_services_bluemix_cloud_integrators?lang=en